# Renaming a file by removing its extension

Tags: c#, file

I have a program which creates documents which are first stored locally. It then sends them to a network folder.

Due to user permissions on their laptops, they are unable to delete off the local drive. The program therefore copies them. In the hope that local permissions are one day changed, it tries to move them, and when that fails it copies them.

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.MasterCopies, "*.xml"))
{
    x = x + 1;
    try
    {
        try
        {    
            string NetworkPath = XMLWork.XMLGetElement(@"D:\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + "\\Digital Statements\\App_Data\\User\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + ".wit", "NetworkMasters");
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string FilePath = NetworkPath;
            File.Move(file, Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName));
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            string NetworkPath = XMLWork.XMLGetElement(@"D:\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + "\\Digital Statements\\App_Data\\User\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + ".wit", "NetworkMasters");
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string FilePath = NetworkPath;
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName));
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    e.Result = x;
    MasterBackups.ReportProgress(x);
}
```

I don't want the program to constantly try and copy files it has already processed. I am thinking the easiest way around this is for it to trim off the file extension ".xml" from them file after it has successfully copied it to the network, therefore on the next run it won't see the file.

How do I achieve this - so the program would see "Test.xml", copy it to the network and then rename the local copy to "Test"?

EDIT - I can rename files locally, I just can't move or delete. The permissions are set by the IT Department and even they aren't sure why it is set this way - but it is!

Comment: If you can't delete a file you can't rename it...

Comment: How many files are you talking about here?

Comment: The fact that delete fails means the file is readonly. You can't rename it.

Comment: Question updated to reflect that I can indeed rename a file - just not move/delete it. The file number varies - could a a couple, could be 25+ depending on when the user last synced.

Comment: Would love to know what setup they have to achieve this as rename requires delete on NTFS AFAIK.

Comment: I can see you use `File.Move` already which is how you would rename files, just `File.Move(oldname, newname);`. Does this not work?

Comment: @Equalsk actually, I have been able to rename running services without being able to remove them. So it seems possible to rename and not delete.

Comment: @Default That's not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating temporary files instead? See the [Path.GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) Method. Not the most ideal solution but if you can't delete them programmatically then you could at least put them somewhere that they will eventually get cleaned up (i.e. when the user runs a disk cleanup).

Answer (score 0):

You could store the already processed file names in a text file or sqlite database that will maintain each file name already processed. Compare against this list before you coping and append/insert into the text/database after each new file copied.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this. Rename the files with a `_copy_Date` at the end of the file. (Before the extension). This way you know when the last time you copied it was without looking into it's file properties.

```
List<String> files = Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.MasterCopies, "*.xml");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    x = x + 1;
    try
    {

        string NetworkPath = XMLWork.XMLGetElement(@"D:\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + "\\Digital Statements\\App_Data\\User\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + ".wit", "NetworkMasters");
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file) + "_Copy_" + DateTime.Now; // Append some info to copyed file name
        string FilePath = NetworkPath;
        if (!files.Contains(FileName)) // Check if copy file is in directory already
        {
            File.Move(file, Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Catch something here
    }
    e.Result = x;
    MasterBackups.ReportProgress(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Equalsk got it - Here is my code.
I copy the file to the network, then trim the ".XML" from the end and replace it with ".DEL" so I can put a tool in to remove the ".DEL"'s once the permissions are sorted.

```
  string NetworkPath = XMLWork.XMLGetElement(@"D:\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + "\\Digital Statements\\App_Data\\User\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.currentUser + ".wit", "NetworkMasters");
                    string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    string LocalPath = Path.GetFullPath(file);
                    string FilePath = NetworkPath;
                    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(FilePath, FileName));
                    string NewFileName = LocalPath.TrimEnd('.', 'x', 'm', 'l');
                    //MessageBox.Show(NewFileName);
                    File.Move(file, NewFileName+".del");
```